# Find class by interface

Tags: typescript

Assume the following code:

```
interface FirstInterface {}
interface SecondInterface {}
interface ThirdInterface {}

class TheClass {
  constructor(howdy: FirstInterface) {}
}

class Foo implements FirstInterface {}
class Bar implements SecondInterface {}
class Whatever implements ThirdInterface {}

[
  new Foo(),
  new Bar(),
  new Whatever()
].forEach(cls => {
  // How to find out which one of the three classes to use here?
  // if(cls instanceof FirstInterface) obviously doesn't work :(
  new TheClass(cls);
});
```

I want to inject the proper class to `TheClass`, which, in this case would be `Foo`.

I know that interfaces are completely gone after compilation - but is there any solution to this?

Reason: my DI Container automatically injects dependencies, which indeed can be interfaces. But when resolving classes which use interfaces in their constructor, I have no idea how to find out which class to use without knowing at least the name of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a discriminant property? Something like this

```
interface FirstInterface {kind: 'firstInterface'}
interface SecondInterface {kind: 'secondInterface'}
interface ThirdInterface {kind: 'thirdInterface'}

class Foo implements FirstInterface {}
class Bar implements SecondInterface {}
class Whatever implements ThirdInterface {}

[
  new Foo(),
  new Bar(),
  new Whatever()
].forEach(cls => {
  // How to find out which one of the three classes to use here?
  if(cls.kind === 'firstInterface') new TheClass(cls);
});
```

You can see a working example on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2FWhat%20about%20using%20a%20discriminant%20property%3F%20Something%20like%20this%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20FirstInterface%20%7Bkind%3A%20'firstInterface'%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20SecondInterface%20%7Bkind%3A%20'secondInterface'%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20ThirdInterface%20%7Bkind%3A%20'thirdInterface'%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20implements%20FirstInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20kind%20%3A%20'firstInterface'%3B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.kind%20%3D%20'firstInterface'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20implements%20SecondInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20kind%20%3A%20'secondInterface'%3B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.kind%20%3D%20'secondInterface'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Whatever%20implements%20ThirdInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20kind%20%3A%20'thirdInterface'%3B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.kind%20%3D%20'thirdInterface'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TheClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(c%3A%20FirstInterface)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20Foo()%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20Bar()%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20Whatever()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D.forEach(cls%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20How%20to%20find%20out%20which%20one%20of%20the%20three%20classes%20to%20use%20here%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if(cls.kind%20%3D%3D%3D%20'firstInterface')%20new%20TheClass(cls)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem for myself by switching from interfaces to abstract classes. You can find my naive DI implementation [here](https://github.com/pavel-agarkov/Midnight-Lizard/blob/master/ts/DI/-DI.ts)